# Nested loop in mips assembly

Tags: c, assembly, mips

I have to write the following C loop in mips assembly:

```
for (i=0;i<5;++i)
{
   for (k=0;k<4;++k)
   {
      printf ("*");
   }
 printf ("\n");
}
```

Here is my code:

```
.data
i: .word 0 
k: .word 0 
limit: .word 4 
line: .word 5 
char: .byte '*'
newline: .byte '\n'

.text
.globl main
main:
lw $t0,i
lw $t1,k
lw $t2,limit
lw $t3,line
print:
beq $t0,$t3,exit    
lb $a0,char
li $v0,11
addi $t1,$t1,1
syscall
bne $t1,$t2,print
addi $t0,$t0,1
lb $a0,newline
li $v0,11
syscall
bne $t0,$t3,print
exit:
li $v0,10
syscall
```

This prints the first line as intended but after newline character the program enters an infinite loop and prints stars constantly.I am really confused on how to deal with nested loops in assembly.I tried to convert the C loops in if conditions and it helped a bit but still something is wrong.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use the simulator's debugging features. Set breakpoints at places of interest (e.g. `beq $t0,$t3,exit` and `bne $t1,$t2,print`) and then run your program.

Comment: Use a label for the start of the outer loop, and a label for the start of the inner loop.  Branch to those labels based on the the respective loops conditionals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before `bne $t0,$t3,print` you have to put `lw $t1, 0` so variable k from the C program would be initialized to 0 before the loop starts again.

No time to double check it but, i think you can get rid of `beq $t0,$t3,exit`.

Comment: True,though i used move $t1,$zero but they are probably equal.Appreciate your help.

Comment: @JohnM.: Yes, that's correct, and equivalent to `li $t1, 0`.  Both will assemble to one instruction.  Possibly different instructions, like `addu $t1, $0, $0` vs. `ori $t1, $0, 0`, but those are both equally efficient.  (BTW, **`lw`** is a load, and not what you need.)